# How to combine produceState and collectAsState in Android composables

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

is there a better way to use `produceState` and `collectAsState`?

```
val stateFlow by produceState<Flow<Stateable>>(initialValue = flowOf(InitialState), true) {

    value = viewModel.reduce(ActivitySearch)

}

val state by stateFlow.collectAsState(initial = InitialState)
```

in my composable?

is there an approach where i can combine the `produceState` with the `collectAsState`?

Comment: What is the point of using `produceState ` with `flow`?

Comment: when i had just collectAsState the viewmodel.reduce call was looping infinitly

Comment: But you do not need to create methods like `reduce(): Flow<>`. 
viewmodel is a state holder and it must expose own state through the properties (State or Flow) - since they are not methods, no infinite calls occur.
If you really want to use the `reduce(): Flow<>` method, then you will need to use LaunchedEffect